# $l_1$ Matrix Norm Inequality

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I am independently studying Numerical Analysis and came upon the following question:

$l_1$ vector norm $\|x\|_1$ is defined as $\|x\|_1=\sum|x_i|$.

How can we show that for the natural matrix norm associated with the $l_1$ vector norm is defined by $\|A\|_1=max_j\sum_{i=1}^n|a_{ij}|$.

To show this, I must first show that $||Ax||_1 /{||x||_1} <= max_j\sum_{i=1}^n|a_{ij}|$ for all $x!=0$. This is where I am totally confused as to what to do. What I tried is the following:

$||Ax||_1 /{||x||_1}$ = $||A||_1 ||x||_1 /{||x||_1}$ = $||A||_1$ which is equal to $||A_1||=max_j\sum_{i=1}^n|a_{ij}|$ for $x!=0$ but this seems too simple and too trivial. Also I am to find an $x$ for which exact equality holds.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If $e_j$ is the unit vector with $(e_j)_i = 1$ for $i=j$, $0$ otherwise,
$\sum_{i=1}^n |a_{ij}| = \|A e_j\|_1$.  In particular, $\|A e_j\|_1 \le \|A\|_1 \|e_j\|_1 = \|A\|_1$, so $\max_j \|A e_j\|_1 \le \|A\|_1$.

On the other hand, for any vector $x$ we have $x = \sum_j x_j e_j$,
so $$\|A x\|_1 = \left\| \sum_j x_j A e_j \right\|_1 \le  \sum_j |x_j| \|A e_j\|_1
\le \sum_j |x_j| \max_j \|A e_j\|_1 = \|x\|_1 \max_j \|A e_j\|_1$$
which says that $\|A\|_1 \le \max_j \|A e_j\|_1$.

Comment: Hi Robert, Is the answer true for a rectangular matrix also? I have a rectangular matrix $V$ of order $p\times n$ say, $p<n$, also $V$ have $p$ orthonormal rows, then can I say $\|V\|_1\le 1$ ?

Comment: $V:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^p$ is an linear map...