# For any matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $\| A \|_{\infty} = \max_{i}\sum_{j=1}^{n} |a_{ij}|$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-explanation, matrix-norms

> For any matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $$\| A \|_{\infty} = \max_{i}\sum_{j=1}^{n} |a_{ij}|$$

---

The proof I saw found a upper bound for $\| A\|_{\infty}$:

$$\dfrac{\|Ax\|_{\infty}}{\| x\|_{\infty}} \leq \max_{i} \sum_{j=1}^{n} |a_{ij}|$$

I could not understand one step, where a vector $\tilde{x}$ is exhibited, such that

$$\tilde{x}=\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  1  & \mbox{if } a_{kj} \geq 0, \ j=1,...,n \\
  -1 & \mbox{if } a_{kj} < 0, \ j=1,...,n
 \end{array}
\right.$$

$a_{kj}$ is the k-th line with maximum $\|.\|_1$, it follows that

$$\dfrac{\| A\tilde{x}\|_{\infty}}{\|\tilde{x}\|_{\infty}}=\max{i} |(A\tilde{x})_i|=\max_i |\sum_{j}^n a_{ij}\tilde{x}_j|\stackrel{?}=|\sum_{j}^n a_{kj}\tilde{x}_j|$$

Someone could explain me the last equality sign?

Comment: Don't know but $\max_i |\sum_{j}^n a_{ij}\tilde{x}_j|=\max_i \sum_{j}^n |a_{ij}|$ with the definition of $\tilde{x}$ given, so that the upper bound is met.

Comment: @Paul It is still not clear to me.

Comment: The upper bound is clear enough? You then need to find a vector in the unit ball for the norm (an n-cube, or square in 2D for example) where the bound is met. Pick the row $k$ of $A$ with the max value of $|(A\tilde{x})_i|$ then $|(A\tilde{x})_k|=|\sum_{j}^n a_{kj} \tilde{x}_j|=\sum_{j}^n |a_{kj}|$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$l_1$ Matrix Norm Inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/561462/l-1-matrix-norm-inequality) It gives a more understandable proof. Btw, where did yours come from?

Answer (score 1):

With the upper bound given above it is sufficient to find one vector $\bar x$ for which the inequality above is an equality. For that we take the line with maximal $\lVert \cdot \rVert_1$-norm which just means that we pick the line $k$ for which
$$\sum_{j=1}^n \lvert a_{kj}\rvert$$
obtains a maximum out of all the $n$ rows. Now
$$\sum_{j=1}^n \lvert a_{kj} \rvert = \sum_{j=1}^n \mathrm{sgn}(a_{kj}) a_{kj} = \sum_{j=1}^n \bar x_j a_{kj}$$
by the definition of the given $\bar x$. On top of that we have $\lVert \bar x \rVert_\infty = \max_{i=1, \dots, n} \lvert \bar x_i \rvert = 1$ and from that we can conclude
$$\frac{\lVert A\bar x \rVert_\infty}{\lVert \bar x \rVert_\infty} = \lVert A\bar x \rVert_\infty = \max_{i=1, \dots, n} \lvert (A\bar x)_i\rvert =\max_{i=1, \dots, n} \left \lvert \sum_{j=1}^n \bar x_j a_{ij} \right \rvert.$$

By the triangle inequality the last line is less than or equal to $\max_{i=1, \dots, n} \sum_{j=1}^n \lvert a_{ij} \rvert = \sum_{j=1}^n \lvert a_{kj} \rvert$ by choice of $k$ as the row with maximal $\lVert \cdot \rVert_1$-norm. But we also have
$$\sum_{j=1}^n \lvert a_{kj} \rvert=\left \lvert \sum_{j=1}^n \bar x_j a_{kj} \right \rvert \le \max_{i=1, \dots, n} \left \lvert \sum_{j=1}^n \bar x_j a_{ij} \right \rvert \le  \max_{i=1, \dots, n} \sum_{j=1}^n \lvert a_{ij} \rvert = \sum_{j=1}^n \lvert a_{kj} \rvert$$
so in fact we have the equality. This means
$$\lVert A \rVert_\infty =\sup_{x \ne 0 }\frac{\lVert A x \rVert_\infty}{\lVert  x \rVert_\infty} \ge \max_{i=1, \dots, n} \lvert a_{ij}\rvert$$
and by the upper bound that you already know we have equality.